# Binary text classification problem with small label-dataset using keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, classification, keras

I want to build a feedforward network with keras. 
My dataset consists of youtube comments with labels 1 : spam and 0 : no spam and I use the Bag-of-words model.
The amount of the spam comments is ca. 5%.
Here is the model I use right now:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=len(txt_dict), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics ['accuracy', precision, recall])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

Now my problem is the model always predict 0, because of the small amount of spam labels.
I had the idea that a low recall must be punished harder, but how can I implement this?

Comment: Use [fit()](https://keras.io/models/model/)'s `class_weight` parameter.